# IServicesCollect Configure is not working, results in "Unable to resolve service for type"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm configuring `JwtIssuerOptions` using `appsettings.json` in a Asp.Net.Core api project (.NET 7), here is my code:

```
public class JwtIssuerOptions
{
   public string Issuer { get; set; }
   public string Audience { get; set; }
   public string JwtSecretKey { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public static void ConfigureJwt(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configManager)
{
    var jwtAppSettingOptions = configManager.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
    if (jwtAppSettingOptions == null)
    {
         throw new Exception("JwtIssuerOptions is null");
    }
    // jwtAppSettingOptions is not null
    services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(jwtAppSettingOptions);
    // I have also tried the following:
    services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(setting => jwtAppSettingOptions.Bind(setting));
    services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(configManager.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions)));
}
```

And I have a `IdentityTokenClaimService` depending on the `JwtIssuerOptions` :

```
public IdentityTokenClaimService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
            JwtIssuerOptions _jwtIssuerOptions)
{
   _userManager = userManager;
   this.jwtIssuerOptions = _jwtIssuerOptions;
}
```

When I build the project, it gives this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'JwtIssuerOptions' while attempting to activate 'IdentityTokenClaimService'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juding From the error message, you inject `JwtIssuerOptions` directly into your service.

You should inject `IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions>`/IOptionsSnapshot..... instead

For Example:

```
public class SomeService:ISomeService
    {
        private readonly IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> _options;
        SomeService(IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> options) 
        {
            _options = options;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `services.Configure<IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions>>(jwtAppSettingOptions)` ? Still not working.

Comment: Check what i've updated, follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: also,don't configure options as you commented